# Find Full or Differential backup from .bak (with powershell or by any other means)

Tags: sql-server, backup, powershell, sql

I'm trying to determine whether an MS SQL backup file (.bak) is Full or Differential.

Is there an easy way to do this? A way of doing this in powershell?

Comment: Which database? E.g. SQLServer, Postgres, MySQL?

Comment: @utrecht edited to clarify, MS SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about MS SQL.

I don't think there is a way to tell just by looking at the file.

This is why it's important to plan your backup process so as to take the guesswork out it, by using different file extensions like .bak, .diff, .trn, etc., to identify what type of file it is.

Maybe you could try the `restore verifyonly` command:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188902.aspx

If it's a lonely diff, SQL will tell you that it's an incomplete set.

Comment: This seems like a totally viable solution. Thanks!